# Karaf: Creating of JDBC datasource fails without log entry

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, apache-karaf

I am new to Karaf (Version 4.3.6) and trying to create a jpa application (based on the Karaf-jpa-example). I'm having problems to understand, how I create a jdbc datasource for my app.

In a Karaf feature I added the following code:

```
    <feature name="herakles-db-datasource" version="${project.version}">
        <config name="org.ops4j.datasource-herakles">
            osgi.jdbc.driver.class=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
            databaseName=herakles_2
            dataSourceName=herakles
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/herakles_2
            user=herakles
            password=ce_eu97
        </config>
        <capability>
            osgi.service;objectClass=javax.sql.DataSource;effective:=active;osgi.jndi.service.name=herakles
        </capability>
        <feature>transaction</feature>
        <feature>jndi</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-config</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-mariadb</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2</feature>
        <feature>jdbc</feature>
    </feature>

    <feature name="herakles-db-api" version="${project.version}">
        <feature version="[2,3)">eclipselink</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:ch.eugster.herakles/herakles-db-api/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>

    <!-- Declarative Service Providers -->
    <feature name="herakles-db-jpa" version="${project.version}">
        <feature>transaction</feature>
        <feature>jndi</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-config</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-h2</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2</feature>
        <feature>jdbc</feature>
        <feature version="[2,3)">jpa</feature>
        <feature>scr</feature>
        <feature version="${project.version}">herakles-db-api</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.19</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:ch.eugster.herakles/herakles-db-jpa/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>

    <feature name="herakles-db-command" version="${project.version}">
        <feature version="${project.version}">herakles-db-api</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:ch.eugster.herakles/herakles-db-command/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>

</features>
```

I add the features using feature:repo-add, after that I do feature:install herakles-db-datasource.

In the Karaf.log I do not find any error entries:

```
2022-04-21T16:49:16,340 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Changes to perform:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,341 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   Region: root
2022-04-21T16:49:16,341 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |     Bundles to install:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,341 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:javax.el/javax.el-api/3.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,342 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:javax.enterprise/cdi-api/2.0.SP1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,342 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:javax.interceptor/javax.interceptor-api/1.2.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,342 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,342 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.3_1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,343 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject/1_3
2022-04-21T16:49:16,343 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,343 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-config/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,343 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-common/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,344 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,344 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Installing bundles:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,344 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:javax.el/javax.el-api/3.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,354 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:javax.enterprise/cdi-api/2.0.SP1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,363 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:javax.interceptor/javax.interceptor-api/1.2.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,372 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,379 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.3_1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,398 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject/1_3
2022-04-21T16:49:16,407 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,420 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-config/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,432 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-common/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,444 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,480 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Starting bundles:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,481 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   javax.el-api/3.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,486 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject/1.0.0.3
2022-04-21T16:49:16,490 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   javax.interceptor-api/1.2.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,496 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   javax.enterprise.cdi-api/2.0.0.SP1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,501 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   javax.transaction-api/1.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,507 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.0.201505202023
2022-04-21T16:49:16,515 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,538 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.pool.common/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,543 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.3.1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,549 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,566 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Done.
2022-04-21T16:49:16,920 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Changes to perform:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,920 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   Region: root
2022-04-21T16:49:16,921 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |     Bundles to install:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,921 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.api/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,921 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.core/1.0.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,921 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.legacy.support/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,922 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.rmi/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,922 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.url/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,922 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy/1.1.12
2022-04-21T16:49:16,922 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.8.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,923 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.9.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,923 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.karaf.jdbc/org.apache.karaf.jdbc.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:16,923 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.karaf.jndi/org.apache.karaf.jndi.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:16,923 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib/3.3.0_1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,923 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-naming/4.20
2022-04-21T16:49:16,924 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.7.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,924 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,924 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,924 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,925 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,925 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-util/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,925 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-mariadb/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,925 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,926 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-tm-api/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,926 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-tm-geronimo/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,926 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-local/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,926 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |       mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-xa/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:16,929 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Installing bundles:
2022-04-21T16:49:16,930 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.api/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,938 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.core/1.0.2
2022-04-21T16:49:16,948 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.legacy.support/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,960 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.rmi/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,972 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.url/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:16,986 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy/1.1.12
2022-04-21T16:49:16,997 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.8.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,019 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.9.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,035 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.karaf.jdbc/org.apache.karaf.jdbc.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,055 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.karaf.jndi/org.apache.karaf.jndi.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,077 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib/3.3.0_1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,122 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-naming/4.20
2022-04-21T16:49:17,134 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.7.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,155 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,167 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,181 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,193 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,209 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-util/9.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,223 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-mariadb/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,234 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,243 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-tm-api/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,255 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-tm-geronimo/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,269 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-local/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,283 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   mvn:org.apache.aries.tx-control/tx-control-service-xa/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,416 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Starting bundles:
2022-04-21T16:49:17,417 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.objectweb.asm/9.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,419 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.objectweb.asm.tree/9.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,421 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.objectweb.asm.commons/9.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,423 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.proxy/1.1.12
2022-04-21T16:49:17,432 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis/9.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,434 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.objectweb.asm.util/9.2.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,436 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.jndi.api/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,438 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.jndi.core/1.0.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,452 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.jndi.rmi/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,457 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.xbean.naming/4.20.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,459 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.karaf.jndi.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,490 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | CommandExtension                 | 44 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.3.6 | Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.jndi.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,491 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.jndi.url/1.1.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,496 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | jndi                             | 100 - org.apache.aries.jndi.url - 1.1.0 | Blueprint support disabled: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer not found by org.apache.aries.jndi.url [100]
2022-04-21T16:49:17,497 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.aries.jndi.legacy.support/1.0.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,501 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib/3.3.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,506 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.commons.commons-pool2/2.9.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,511 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.mariadb.jdbc/2.7.2
2022-04-21T16:49:17,521 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | DataSourceRegistration           | 93 - org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config - 1.5.0 | Found DataSourceFactory. Creating DataSource herakles
2022-04-21T16:49:17,527 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.mariadb/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,534 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | DataSourceRegistration           | 93 - org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config - 1.5.0 | Found DataSourceFactory. Creating DataSource herakles
2022-04-21T16:49:17,536 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | DataSourceRegistration           | 93 - org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.config - 1.5.0 | Found DataSourceFactory. Creating DataSource herakles
2022-04-21T16:49:17,538 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.transx.pax-transx-tm-api/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,543 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.transx.pax-transx-tm-geronimo/0.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,554 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.commons.commons-dbcp2/2.8.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,559 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   tx-control-service-local/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,565 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | Activator                        | 118 - tx-control-service-local - 1.0.1 | Registering a new Local TransactionControl service with properties {service.vendor=Apache Aries, service.description=The Apache Aries Transaction Control Service for Local Transactions, osgi.local.enabled=true}
2022-04-21T16:49:17,570 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   tx-control-service-xa/1.0.1
2022-04-21T16:49:17,575 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | Activator                        | 119 - tx-control-service-xa - 1.0.1 | Registering for configuration updates {service.vendor=Apache Aries, service.pid=org.apache.aries.tx.control.service.xa, service.description=Managed Service for the Apache Aries Transaction Control Service with XA Transactions}
2022-04-21T16:49:17,582 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.apache.karaf.jdbc.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,608 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | CommandExtension                 | 44 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.3.6 | Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.jdbc.core/4.3.6
2022-04-21T16:49:17,610 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 |   org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.pool.dbcp2/1.5.0
2022-04-21T16:49:17,620 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | TransactionManager               | 94 - org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.pool.common - 1.5.0 | TransactionManager service detected. Providing support for XA DataSourceFactories
2022-04-21T16:49:17,624 | INFO  | features-3-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 18 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.3.6 | Done.
```

When I do jdbc:ds-list, I get:

```
Name │ Service Id │ Product │ Version │ URL │ Status
─────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┼───────────
141  │            │         │         │     │ Error null
```

Can anyone help me, how to solve this problem?

Thank you Christian

Comment: Try removing the `"` from  `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/herakles_2`. You can also use config:list -s to list all registered configuration files and `config:property-list -p <configName>` to see the values.

Comment: That helped. How embarrassing. Sorry for that

Comment: All too common mistake when juggling between XML, JSON and properties files.